# How to escape file path in SED?

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to replace `$fileWithPath` in `$file`, however this doesn't work because (I think) path is not escaped. How to escape it?

```
sed -i 's/${fileWithPath}/HAHA/g' $file
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

```
sed -i 's|'$fileWithPath'|HAHA|g' file
```

Single quotes define a string literal. Putting the variable outside the literal allows the shell to expand that part.

Also: if you are going to parse paths, use a delimiter in the sed command that doesn't confuse with the directory delimiter "/".

Comment: Beware that if `$fileWithPath` contains whitespace, the wrong pattern is inserted.

Comment: Your bonus tip about changing the delimiter for file paths was a life saver!

Comment: I think you have too much quotes in your command. My example `sed -i 's|auth-user-pass nordvpn.txt|auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/nordvpn.txt|g' *.ovpn` seems to work.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz it will work as long as you don't need to expand a variable. My example used a variable so I had to use two single quotes sections (otherwise the variable wouldn't exapand). An option is to use double quotes instead, but that adds other effects to the sed string.

Answer (score 23):

A better way for literal strings with forward slashes:

```
sed -i "s|my/path|my/other/path|g" myFileOfPaths.txt
```

Comment: This one deserved an Oscar! Simple and elegant

Answer (score 14):

In circumstances where the replacement string or pattern string contain slashes, you can make use of the fact that GNU sed allows an alternative delimiter for the substitute command. Common choices for the delimiter are the pipe character **|** or the hash **#** - the best choice of delimiting character will often depend on the type of file being processed. In your case you can try

```
sed -i 's#'$fileWithPath'#HAHA#g' $file
```

The character 'g' after last **#** is used to change all occurrences in file if you need to change only first occurrence then remove the 'g'.