# How do I use variables in a sed command?

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I tried the following code to replace `QQ` with `ZZ`, but it doesn't do what I want:

```
var1=QQ
sed -i 's/$var1/ZZ/g' $file
```

However, this code does what I want:

```
sed -i 's/QQ/ZZ/g' $file
```

How do I use variables in `sed`?

Comment: see [my answer in this post of yours](http://askubuntu.com/questions/76785/how-to-escape-file-path-in-sed/76825#76825)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern

Answer (score 746, accepted):

The shell is responsible for expanding variables. When you use single quotes for strings, its contents will be treated literally, so `sed` now tries to replace every occurrence of the literal `$var1` by `ZZ`.

#### Using double quotes

Use double quotes to make the shell expand variables while preserving whitespace:

```
sed -i "s/$var1/ZZ/g" "$file"
```

When you require the quote character in the replacement string, you have to precede it with a backslash which will be interpreted by the shell. In the following example, the string `quote me` will be replaced by `"quote me"` (the character `&` is interpreted by `sed`):

```
sed -i "s/quote me/\"&\"/" "$file"
```

#### Using single quotes

If you've a lot shell meta-characters, consider using single quotes for the pattern, and double quotes for the variable:

```
sed -i 's,'"$pattern"',Say hurrah to &: \0/,' "$file"
```

Notice how I use `s,pattern,replacement,` instead of `s/pattern/replacement/`, I did it to avoid interference with the `/` in `\0/`.

#### Example

The shell then runs the above command `sed` with the next arguments (assuming `pattern=bert` and `file=text.txt`):

```
-i
s,bert,Say hurrah to &: \0/,
text.txt
```

If `file.txt` contains `bert`, the output will be:

```
Say hurrah to bert: \0/
```

Comment: How would one pass the "/g" option using this comma separated form?

Comment: @b.long It's a `g` option, so you would pass `s,foo,bar,g` instead.

Comment: your single quote example isparticularly useful, covers sed using regex pattern pretty nicely!

Comment: In case you are tempted to use `\\0` instead of `\0`, it should not be done when `\0` is enclosed in single quotes. Otherwise `sed` will substitute the pattern for a literal `\0` instead of the whole match.

Comment: Did the trick for me.

Comment: using `#` as a delimiter is possible too: `sed -i -e 's#$HOME/$SOME_PATH#$HOME/$ANOTHER_PATH#g'`

Comment: Or, for the uber-paranoid (like myself), `sed 's/'"${foo}"'/replacement/'`

Comment: ${foo} is the one working for me

Comment: @leetbacoon Your paranoia saved me a hell lot of work. I couldn't use the above patterns for my task-specific reasons.

Comment: @mnis Glad to hear that helped!

Comment: @leetbacoon your approach is the only one that helped me with the following replacement: `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/UUID=[A-Fa-f0-9-]*/UUID='"${new_uuid}"'/2' </etc/fstab | sudo tee /etc/fstab2 > /dev/null`

Answer (score 235):

We can use variables in `sed` using double quotes:

```
sed -i "s/$var/r_str/g" file_name
```

If you have a slash `/` in the variable then use different separator, like below:

```
sed -i "s|$var|r_str|g" file_name
```

Comment: If you have a slash `/` in the variable => This saved me ! My variable is a url and it contains `/`. Switching to use `|` as separator fixed my issue

Comment: Thumb up for "if you have a slash in the variable"

Comment: @sonlexqt, related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366816/sed-fails-with-unknown-option-to-s-error/9366940#9366940

Comment: Mannnn... I had a forward slash in my var and was pulling my hair on that.. this was a life saver... Thanks a ton.

Comment: Indeed the variables may contain paths and in that case, delimiters should be something other than slashes. Thanks for that great tip!

Comment: The "|" was gold. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like everyone here is replacing some URLs. Thank you guys

Answer (score 2):

To expand (pun intended) on [@mani's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/508174/743914),

- this solution will work for regular expressions fed to other commands, such as `perl`
- use double quotes around the regex (yes, even under Unixy systems) in
  order to expand the variable as expected
- `|` may appear in your variable's value as well, so don't be scared to try other delimiters