# How to find text and replace that line if exists with terminal otherwise just append line to end

Tags: bash, command-line, swap, sed

I want to put in `sudo gedit /etc/sysctl.conf` the one line `vm.swappiness=10` which I sometimes change.

By default this line doesnt exist so I use `echo "vm.swappiness=10" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf`.

If I would always be putting the same exact line `vm.swappiness=10`, then in case I want to replace I could use `sudo sed -i 's/vm.swappiness=10/vm.swappiness=1/g' /etc/sysctl.conf` **But** since there could be `vm.swappiness=12` or something else, I want--with just a single command--to find if, in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, there exists line starting `vm.swappiness=`. Then if it does exist I want to remove **the whole line** (then by appending `&& echo "vm.swappiness=1" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf` to that command, it would also subsequently add the new configuration line that I want to the end.

**But** again since there could be a lot of different parameters in one line, it wouldn't be good to delete it all, but would be better to change only the number (to the immediate right of `vm.swappiness=`).

What you think? Would it be better to search for **vm.swappiness=x(x(x))** with 1 to 3 numbers (of course, 100 also exists...), replace if it's there (by putting it into a variable and using a command like `` `sudo sed -i 's/$oldline/$newline/g' ``), and if not then just append `vm.swappiness=10`?

Comment: By the way, this is tangential to the fundamental topic of your question, but if you're manually editing a file (like `/etc/sysctl.conf`) with `gedit` (or, more generally, running any other graphical program as root unless you know it doesn't touch any user-specific configuration files and are prepared to manually fix permissions on your `.Xauthority` file if necessary), you should use `gksu` (or `gksudo`) instead of `sudo`. So you'd run `gksu gedit /etc/sysctl.conf` instead of `sudo gedit /etc/sysctl.conf`. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
sed 's/vm.swappiness=[0-9]*/vm.swappiness=1/g' /etc/sysctl.conf
```

If you don't mind how many digits your number has.

If you want a maximum of 3 digits, you need extended (modern) regular expressions rather than basic regular expressions (BRE's). You then need to provide the `-E` parameter

```
sed -E 's/vm.swappiness=[0-9]{1,3}/vm.swappiness=1/g' /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Comment: Ouh yes your line is good ok for changing existing but what if it doesnt exist jet? how to use this solution with below solution? To make test if exists then change if not then do what your line does.

Comment: perfect, short and all what is needed. Nothing else can be added. finds exact line with any number containing in settings

Answer (score 7):

You can do such replacements with **awk**.

```
awk '/^vm.swappiness/ {print "replacement"; found=1} !/^vm.swappiness/ {print $0} END {if (!found) {print "appended" }}' filename
```

The *filename* parameter at the end is the name of the text file that contains the lines.

The above command replaces any line that begins with `wm.swappiness` with `replacement` (modify to your need). Otherwise prints out the original lines.

If a replacement was made, it is remembered in the `found` variable. Thus if no replacement was made, the `END` block appends one line with the `appended` string (this should also be modified).

(Please note that I am not taking into account the permissions, this is solving only the replacement or append problem).

Comment: It allways gives me appended. i also tryd without ^ 4 variants (one/both with/out ^) and still gives appended

`man awk | grep abc
       [abc...]   character list, matches any of the characters abc....
       [^abc...]  negated character list, matches any character except abc....
       %x, %X  An unsigned hexadecimal number (an integer).  The %X format uses ABCDEF instead of abcdef.
              /abc/     { ... ; f(1, 2) ; ... }`

Comment: Could you compare your test with mine, it seems to be working for me? http://pastie.org/2831658

Comment: I found it was W instead of V. this far its woking. Thx.
now how could i then put in thouse commands? with/out filename variablable couse maybe sometime append in another file and how to in same file all commands

Comment: Oh, sorry for that! I have not really concentrated on the exact text to be replaced, only the method. I'll edit the post to correct that.

Comment: Two methods come to my mind: 1.) set awk variables with `-v var=value`, so you can use them inside the awk script. 2.) Or see this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/76808/how-to-use-variables-in-sed (it demonstrates how to insert variables into quoted strings).

Comment: I cant understand from there and cant find how then to change that line so my lines would go in there interpreted correctly.

Comment: To supply "replacement" value for the awk script you can use: `awk -v replacement="your_value" '/^vm.swappiness/ {print replacement; found=1} ...'`. Please note the omission of the quotes around the replacement variable after the print statement and the `-v` assignment for this variable. You can use the same method for providing the "appended" value.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing:

```
( sysctl vm.swappiness=10 ) > /dev/null

if [[ `grep "vm.swappiness=" /etc/sysctl.conf | wc -l` -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "vm.swappiness=60" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
fi

sed -i -r 's~^vm.swappiness[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*[0-9]*$~vm.swappiness=10~' /etc/sysctl.conf
```