# How to get Lubuntu to use generic application names

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, launcher, lxpanel

As you know, many application have a generic name.

For example, the generic name of Audacious is: `Music Player`.

How do you get Lubuntu to use this name instead of the regular name.

I realize that a lot of the applications have the same name and generic name, but that is okay.

Note: I am talking about the lxpanel menu.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about in a program menu (lxmenu), or shortcuts on a desktop or panel bar? For those you should be able to add new shortcuts with the generic name (or any name) you'd like. Or a "personal" section with just the apps you commonly used, named however you'd prefer (that's what I'd do).

But, since you clarified that ***"I would like to change all the names to the generic names at once, not do them individually ... Each application has a generic name built-in to its .desktop file"*** here's an answer to "how to do that."

This uses some command line tools like `grep` & `sed`  to search for the "Name=..." part and replace it with the "GernericName=..." part.

### **NOTE:**

- You should use a local copy of the .desktop files by placing them in your `~/.local/share/applications/` first, with

  `cp -R --no-clobber -v /usr/share/applications/ ~/.local/share > ~/cp-applications.log`

  (this may add more files than you want or need, but it writes a **"log"** to `~/cp-applications.log` of what's been copied to where in case you want to undo it later) but leaving the original's alone, and not overwriting any local files already there. I'm also using `sed`'s `-i` option to make a backup copy of the files too named *.BAK. And .
- If you ever want to go back to the original versions of the .desktop files, you can overwrite the .desktop file with it's .desktop.BAK copy, or with the original from `/usr/share/applications/`.
- If there are other .desktop files you'd like to play with, you could search everywhere for them if you like with `find / -type f -name "*.desktop"` (piped to less, or a file perhaps) but that will return more than you want.
- And if you want the language-specific generic name just edit to hit that one (for example "GenericName[en_GB]=").

This only changes the first occurrence of "Name=" (so it leaves things like Firefox's "Open a New Window" as-is):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
targetdir=~/.local/share/applications/

for i in $(grep -l "^GenericName=" "$targetdir"/*.desktop)
do
    echo Hit on $i
    tmphit=$(sed -n 's/^GenericName=//p' "$i")
    echo Generic name is:"$tmphit"
    sed -iBAK "0,/^Name=/s/^Name=.*/Name=$tmphit/g" "$i" || echo "SED FAILED!!!!"
done
```

There's probably a way to do this with a one-liner in `perl` or even `sed`, `awk`, but "meh".

Feel free to remove the echo's too. And see these answers for more info:

- [How to use variables in sed command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76808/how-to-use-variables-in-sed-command)
- [grep for contents after pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358547/grep-for-contents-after-pattern)
- [How to use sed to replace only the first occurrence in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148451/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-file)

---

Or if you want to run them from a terminal, just add some links to the real program, under whatever generic name you'd like. Find the program's location with `which` (often `/usr/bin`) and link with `ln`.

Comment: I mean from the program menu. Also, I would like to change all the names to the generic names at once, not do them individually.

Comment: I don't think you can change them all at once, since each one has a different name to start with, and targets a different application...

Comment: Each application has a generic name built-in to its .desktop file. [Like here](https://github.com/audacious-media-player/audacious/blob/master/audacious.desktop).

Comment: @DKBose that's the right track, but `grep -L` returns "files without match", lower case `-l` returns files with matches and does get things going

Comment: True, looks like maybe 15% in /usr/share/applications/ have generic names... and those that do have 50 or so different names for different languages too... but I got a little script that should rename some stuff ok - no going back though :)

Comment: A high percentage of questions on here don't get any answers, I'm sure the askers would be grateful for even the start of the "perfect answer." And if there are better answers from someone else, they'll get voted to the top, that's the StackExhange model right?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Perhaps using the user-specific directory can help: `sed ...  $DESKTOP_FILE > ~/.local/share/applications/$DESKTOP_FILE`.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Oh, sorry, I didn't see that comment!

Comment: d'oh! Think I got it...... sometimes it's not worth the effort of just posting an idea

Comment: I removed a 1GB of text :)

Comment: I won't bother you any more, but you'd probably not want to copy *all* desktop files locally! just the ones to (potentially) edit. There are many .desktop files in there to built up your desktop for example. Copying them locally is a bad idea. Did that once, had to repair it with a live usb.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Double-d'oh. Thought of that with the `cp` command, I'll look for a "no-clobber" type option maybe... or I'll just paste your comment in there instead :) [maybe I'll delete some comments too...] Thanks for the help