# manipulate string that is streamed into a file using bash

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I'm trying to pipe multiple lines into a text file while manipulating the string that is being piped according to a sequence

```
cmd="My string 00"

for i in $(seq -f "%02g" 00 05); \
  do \
  echo $(echo $cmd | sed -e 's|00|$(echo $i)|g') >> outfile.txt ;  \
done
```

doesn't work.
The output should look like this:

```
My string 00  
My string 01  
My string 02  
My string 03  
My string 04  
My string 05
```

but the output is:

```
My string $(echo $i)
My string $(echo $i)
My string $(echo $i)
My string $(echo $i)
My string $(echo $i)
My string $(echo $i)
```

Comment: Use `"` instead of `'` in your `sed` command. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/76808/how-do-i-use-variables-in-a-sed-command

Comment: ...and if you want 2 digits in the output, use `seq -f "%02g"`.

Comment: `seq -f "%05g" 00 05 | sed 's/.../My string /'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in {00000..00005}; do echo "${i/???/My string }"; done >> outfile.txt
```

Output to outfile.txt:

```
My string 00
My string 01
My string 02
My string 03
My string 04
My string 05
```

Comment: Can you eplain the '???' part? Why is the order of i and the string inverted? Would this also work if the string was encoded in a variable ($cmd)?

Comment: This is part of bash's [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). `echo "$i"` or `echo "${i}"` outputs content of variable `i`. `echo "${i/???/My string }"` replaces in output first three characters with your string. A variable with your string is here possible, too.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it all with `printf` and brace expansion:

```
$ printf 'My string %02d\n' {0..5} > outfile.txt

$ cat outfile.txt 
My string 00
My string 01
My string 02
My string 03
My string 04
My string 05
```

If for some reason you *must* generate the input sequence with more padding than you really want, `printf` will reformat it for you:

```
$ printf 'My string %02d\n' $(seq -f "%05g" 00 05)
My string 00
My string 01
My string 02
My string 03
My string 04
My string 05
```

Comment: I cannot hard code the string because it is much more complicated as shown above. I assume printf cannot print variables (like $cmd)?

Comment: @mcExchange you can expand variables within the printf format string provided it is soft-quoted e.g. `cmd='My string'; printf "$cmd %02d\n" {0..5}` **however** you need to beware of anything in `$cmd` that might be interpreted as a format character. Regardless, it sounds like you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)