# Delete ranges of lines, but skip the comments which come in between the lines

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a file with the following contents:

```
Windows user
I love windows
Windows 10
# I like it
# I want to keep these two lines
Just started with my job
New to shell scripting as well
New to Mac
Please help!

#EOF
```

I want to delete all the lines:

starting from "`I love windows`" to "`New to shell scripting as well`", but keep the comments that are present between these lines.

So, the desired output should appear as below:

```
Windows user
# I like it
# I want to keep these two lines
New to Mac
Please help!

#EOF
```

I used `sed` command to delete the range of lines using the line numbers

```
sed '2,7d' file
```

But this command deletes the comments as well, which I want preserved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using:

```
sed '2,7{/^[[:blank:]]*#/!d}' infile
```

This is normally deleting lines from 2~7 but not the lines that starts with a hash as known as a commented line.

The `[[:blank:]]` character class is used to match and keep those lines that it's a commented line but took whitespaces at behind too either zero or more whitespace.

To be more specifically using the patterns given:

```
sed '/I love windows/,/New to shell scripting as well/ {/^[[:blank:]]*#/!d}' infile
```

standard-Complaint `sed` solution would be:

```
sed -e '2,7{' -e '/^[[:space:]]*#/!d' -e '}' infile
```

to read the line number from a variable, just double-quote your variables like `"$line"` (***related***: [How do I use variables in a sed command?](https://askubuntu.com/q/76808/283843).)

```
line=2; sed -e "$line"',7{' -e '/^[[:space:]]*#/!d' -e '}' infile
```

The output is:

```
Windows user
# I like it
# I want to keep these two lines
New to Mac
Please help!

#EOF
```