# how to replace a word between double quotes?

Tags: scripts

I need to replace a word between the quotes after equal sign using sed. but I'm unable to do it please suggest?
#mfsbsd.rootpwhash=""
look like
#mfsbsd.rootpwhash="wsnk&*32jk"

```
cat loader | sed -e 's|["\'']||g' | sed 's/rootpwhash="[^"]*"/rootpwhash="abcd"/'
```

Comment: Did you find any answer useful? Providing feedback is useful for the community.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a matter of systematically escaping the `" with the` \ character? This works for me:

```
$ echo Name=\"\" | sed -e 's/\"\"/\"This should be filled in\"/'Name="This should be filled in"
```

To replace anything that is originally between the `""`:

```
$ echo Name=\"Original\" | sed -e 's/\".*\"/\"This should be filled in\"/'
Name="This should be filled in"
```

Comment: wow!nice. but i need user variable replaced word, im getting unmatched ''' error, echo mfsbsd.rootpwhash=\" \" | sed -e "s/\".*\"/$text/"

Comment: That is not in your question. If, after having an answer on this question ("how to replace a word between double quotes?" is what you asked!) specific issues remain, then outline the specific issue in a new, specific question. It is not allowed here to change the nature of your question after the fact, so feel free to ask a different question.

Answer (score 0):

If your *key-value* pair is structured one per line, you only need to match the key-part. i.e., if you don't have to *match* the value too.

```
text=new; cat loader | \
sed "s/\(mfsbsd.rootpwhash\)=.*/\1=\"$text\"/"
```

Comment: good, mfsbsd.rootpwhash=sri its printing like this with cat loader | sed "s/\(mfsbsd.rootpwhash\)=.*/\1="$text"/" . how can i add double qoute to the string(sri)

Comment: `/\1=\"$text\"/"`

Comment: sorry to ask precise answer im new to scripting. i tried this not working cat loader | sed "s/\(mfsbsd.rootpwhash\)=.*/\1=\"$text\"/ printing mfsbsd.rootpwhash=sri" before s not coming another double qoute.

Comment: looks like you have missed the last quote

Comment: sed: 1: "s/".*"/"%6%GOrxqIbx.CmZ ...": bad flag in substitute command: 'l' im getting this error always. when im running this sed -i -e "s/\(mfsbsd.rootpwhash\)=.*/\1=\"$newpass\"/" /bootpool/boot/loader.conf
whenever i run this getting error bad flag in substitute command: 'l'  with different letter which is not exists in my command. any sol

Comment: if you are going to do an in-place substitution you need to place "loader" as an input file instead `text=new; sed -i 's/\(mfsbsd.rootpwhash\)=.*/\1="'"$text"'"/' loader`

Comment: @Sreekanth Chityala use `` when commenting code ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [double quotes](https://askubuntu.com/a/76842/226614), and escape special characters in your substitute variable

```
$ export TESTVAR="wsnk\&\*32jk"
$ cat loader | sed -e "s/\".*\"/\"$TESTVAR\"/"
#mfsbsd.rootpwhash="wsnk&*32jk"
```