# Introducing blank lines between matched sections

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have the following bash function that uses `sed` to extract sections occurring between `## Mode: org` and `## # End of org`, where `#` is the comment character.  Finally I remove the comment character and any spaces.

This is my input

```
cat /home/flora/docs/recnotes.txt
   ## Mode: org
   #  Assigns shell positional parameters or changes the values of shell
   #  options.  The -- option assigns the positional parameters to the
   #  arguments of {set}, even when some of them start with an option
   #  prefix `-'.
   ## # End of org

     ;; Mode: org
     ;  Assigns shell positional parameters or changes the values of shell
     ;  options.  The -- option assigns the positional parameters to the
     ;  arguments of {set}, even when some of them start with an option
     ;  prefix `-'.
     ;; # End of org
 
       @c Mode: org
       @c  Assigns shell positional parameters or changes the values of shell
       @c  options.  The -- option assigns the positional parameters to the
       @c  arguments of {set}, even when some of them start with an option
       @c  prefix `-'.
       @c # End of org
```

Here is the bash function with implementation in `sed`.

```
capture ()
{
 local efile="$1"

 local charcl begorg endorg

 charcl_ere='^[[:space:]]*([#;!]+|@c|\/\/)[[:space:]]*'
 charcl_bre='^[[:space:]]*\([#;!]\+\|@c\|\/\/\)[[:space:]]*'

 begorg="${charcl_bre}"'Mode: org$'
 endorg="${charcl_bre}"'# End of org$'

 mdr='^Mode: org$' ; edr='^# End of org$'

 sed -n "/$begorg/,/$endorg/ s/$charcl_bre//p" "$efile" |
  sed "/$mdr\|$edr/d"
}
```

Originally, I had the two commands as

```
begorg='${charcl_bre}Mode: org$'
endorg='${charcl_bre}# End of org$'
```

which were not expanding the variable `charcl_bre`.

The output is

```
Assigns shell positional parameters or changes the values of shell
options.  The -- option assigns the positional parameters to the
arguments of {set}, even when some of them start with an option
prefix `-'.
Assigns shell positional parameters or changes the values of shell
options.  The -- option assigns the positional parameters to the
arguments of {set}, even when some of them start with an option
prefix `-'.
Assigns shell positional parameters or changes the values of shell
options.  The -- option assigns the positional parameters to the
arguments of {set}, even when some of them start with an option
prefix `-'.
```

What I would like to do is have a blank line between sections.

Comment: What's the question again? Please make sure your question is clear and definite.

Comment: Variables won't expand in single quotes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use variables in a sed command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76808/how-do-i-use-variables-in-a-sed-command)

Answer (score 0):

According to your [latest edit](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1373240/19), you just need to have a blank line between the different comment sections. You can do that by changing the last `sed` command from:

```bsh
sed "/$mdr\|$edr/d"
```

to:

```bsh
sed "/$mdr/d; s/$edr//"
```

This changes the `sed` command from deleting both `$mdr` and `$edr` lines to only deleting the `$mdr` line and replacing the `$edr` line with an empty string, effectively keeping the blank line you want.

The output is:

```
Assigns shell positional parameters or changes the values of shell
options.  The -- option assigns the positional parameters to the
arguments of {set}, even when some of them start with an option
prefix `-'.

Assigns shell positional parameters or changes the values of shell
options.  The -- option assigns the positional parameters to the
arguments of {set}, even when some of them start with an option
prefix `-'.

Assigns shell positional parameters or changes the values of shell
options.  The -- option assigns the positional parameters to the
arguments of {set}, even when some of them start with an option
prefix `-'.
```