# Delete all lines from a line with certain string until another line with a diffrent string in a file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sed, awk

`file.txt`:

```
start some text works "HELLO" foo test
  sum
  other
end

start som "other" line with text 'also'
  thing
  foo
end
```

and I want to delete the line in which `"HELLO"` is located and then delete all following lines until a line which has `end` written on it and nothing else!

I know this is a rather weird idea but I'm hoping either some basic bash command could do this or a function to which I pass the first string and the second and it deletes them and all in between!

The file should be looking like this at the end:

```
start som "other" line with text 'also'
  thing
  foo
end
```

#### THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not bash, but sed:

```
$ sed '/"HELLO"/,/^end$/d' file.txt

start som "other" line with text 'also'
  thing
  foo
end
```

or awk:

```
$ awk '/"HELLO"/,/^end$/{next} 1' file.txt

start som "other" line with text 'also'
  thing
  foo
end
```

Comment: And what if wanted to make `"HELLO"` and `end` variables, I tried modifying your code but I may have broken I that way

Comment: @TroopekYT see [How do I use variables in a sed command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76808/how-do-i-use-variables-in-a-sed-command)

Comment: thank you for the reply