# sed is being confused by my replacement string

Tags: sed

I need to change a single line in the file /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome

exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@"

to

exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@" --test-type --no-sandbox

So my command is:

sed -i 's/exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@"/exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@" --test-type --no-sandbox/' /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome

Which returns:

sed: -e expression #1, char 37: unknown option to `s'

I have searched and found that characters in the command are confusing sed, but I can't seem to find an answer to which ones or how to form it properly.
Can anyone help me to edit my command to the proper syntax?

Comment: You need to escape the slashes or use an alternate regex delimiter - see for example [How to escape file path in SED?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76785/how-to-escape-file-path-in-sed)

Comment: you can check this out https://dwaves.de/tools/escape/

Comment: @IanPrice you'd replace the ones being used as sed delimiters - to distinguish them from the literal ones in the pattern and replacement text

Comment: Ok.  I appreciate the replies, but I still don't get it.  All I need to do is replace a line of text with another line of text.  And I really do appreciate pointing me to resources to learn how to do it myself, but can anyone please just copy/edit my command and tell me the answer?  I have been working on this silly thing for like 2 hours so far.

Comment: @glennjackman, THANK YOU!  That was a great way to help me understand.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `s/pattern/replace/` use something like `s!pattern!replace!` (or a different character if you don't like `!`) -- this is because both the pattern and replacement string contain the `/` character.

Your sed command is

```
s/exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@"/exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@" --test-type --no-sandbox/
```

- the pattern is `exec -a "$0" "$HERE`,
- the replacement is `chrome" "$@"`
- and then the flags (`s/re/repl/flags`) are `exec`

  - there is an `e` flag, but `x` and `c` are not recognized.

Also note that `$` is a special character in a recular expression, and it needs to be escaped.

Try this:

```
s!exec -a "\$0" "\$HERE/chrome" "\$@"!&  --test-type --no-sandbox!
```

- `&` in the replacement string is replaced with the text that matched the pattern

Alternately, for lines that match "exec ... chrome ...", add the flags to the end of the line:

```
\!exec -a "\$0" "\$HERE/chrome" "\$@"! s/$/ --test-type --no-sandbox/
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thank you.  What worked for me is:

```
sed -i 's!exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@"!exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@" --test-type --no-sandbox'! /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
```